# How to reduce CPU usage?

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-usage

I have to decode some byte array(raw data). It can consist of basic data types(int,unsigned int,char,short etc.).According to defined structure, i need to interpret them. below is example:

```
struct testData
{ 
 int a;
char c;
};
   unsigned char** buf = {0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x41}
   example byte array(in little endian) : 0100000041

   should give decoding like : a = 1, c = 'A'
```

The sample data can be very big and the sample structure( e.g. testData) can contain 200 - 3000 fields.
If I use am casting to read the appropriate data from **buf and set pointer like below:

```
    int a = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(*buf);
    *buf += 4;
    char c = **buf;
    *buf += 1;
```

My CPU usage is quite high if number of fileds need to be decoded are high. example:

```
    struct testData
    {
     int element1;
     char element2;
     int element3;
      ... ...
     ... ...
      short element200;
     char element201;
     char element202;
    }
```

Is there a way to reduce the CPU load as well as keep decoding very fast?

I have two constraints:

1. "Structure can contain padding byte."
2. I do not have control on how structure will be defined. Structure can contain nested elements as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
int a = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(*buf);
```

Don't use `reinterpret_cast`. You are lying to the compiler and forcing unaligned accesses. Worse, you are *hiding* from the compiler the very information it needs to optimize your code -- that the pointer is actually to characters. Instead, code what you mean as straightforward as possible, which is:

```
int a=static_cast<int>(*buf[0]) |
     (static_cast<int>(*buf[1])<<8) |
     (static_cast<int>(*buf[2])<<16) |
     (static_cast<int>(*buf[3])<<24);
```

This is simple, clear, and what you actually want. The compiler will have no problem optimizing it. (And, it will work regardless of your platform's endianness.)

Comment: is n't it that reading byte by byte and shifting operation will be slower than reading multiple bytes using casting?

Comment: @learningstack Maybe, maybe not. It may depend on the platform. But I don't have to worry about it because I use good compilers and I don't lie to them. The cast lies to the compiler about the alignment and tricks it into producing bad code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply map the struct to the buffer, as long as the struct is properly packed:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct testData
    {
     int element1;
     char element2;
     int element3;
      ... ...
     ... ...
      short element200;
     char element201;
     char element202;
    }
#pragma pack(pop)
```

You should also declare the structure in a alignment sensible way, don't mix `int` followed by `char` followed by `int`... Then if you read the data in an aligned buffer, a simple cast of the buffer to `testData*` would give you access to all members. This way you would avoid all those gratuitous copies. If you read the structure in forward fashion (`p->element1`, then read `p->element2` then `p->element3` and so on) [hardware prefetch](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimizing-application-performance-on-intel-coret-microarchitecture-using-hardware-implemented-prefetchers/) should kick in and give a big boost.

Further enhancements would require actual measurements of hot spots. Also, check this book out from the library and read it: [The Software Optimization Cookbook](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. But I have two constraints:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. But I have two constraint:

1. "Structure can contain padding byte."
2. I do not have control on how structure will be defined. Structure can contain compound elements(struct,union,arrays etc.) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Further to David Schwartz's response, you can tidy this up by writing some helper template functions. I'd suggest something like this (untested).

```
template<typename T>
const unsigned char * read_from_buffer( T* value, const unsigned char * buffer);

template<>
const unsigned char * read_from_buffer<int>( int* value, const unsigned char * buffer)
{
   *value = static_cast<int>(*buf[0]) |
     (static_cast<int>(*buf[1])<<8) |
     (static_cast<int>(*buf[2])<<16) |
     (static_cast<int>(*buf[3])<<24);
   return buffer+4'
}

template<>
const unsigned char * read_from_buffer<char>( char * value, const unsigned char * buffer )
{
  *value = *buffer;
  return buffer+1;
}

struct TestData
{
  int a;
  char c;
};

int main()
{
  unsigned char buf[] = {0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x41};
  unsigned char * ptr = buf;

  TestData data;
  ptr = read_from_buffer( &data.a, ptr );
  ptr = read_from_buffer( &data.c, ptr );
}
```

You could encapsulate this even further and add error checking etc and you'd have a nice binary stream like interface.

Comment: is n't it that reading byte by byte and shifting operation will be slower than reading multiple bytes using casting?